# Expo shortcut <Super>s doesn't work in classic desktop

Tags: 11.04, gnome, shortcuts

I have bound the `<Super>s` key in the CompizConfig Settings Manager but whenever I press the `<Super>s` the power menu from Indicator Applet Complete shows up:

[image: power menu]

I can bind Expo to any other key (like `<Super>q`) and that works fine but I would really like to use `<Super>s` because I am used to it and it's the default in Unity.

I've checked in Keyboard Shortcuts but the `<Super>s` key (Super is called Mod4 here) isn't bound to anything.

Is there a way to stop the power menu from showing?

**EDIT:** I have noticed that the problem only occurs if I have the Indciator Applet complete or the Indicator applet session in my panel.

Comment: This does only work if Compiz is running (it works fine here in a *Classic* session). Are you sure you didn't start a *Classic (no effects)* session?

Comment: Compiz is running and Expo works if I bind it to somthing else than <Super>s.

Comment: Weird. It *is* working here (a relatively fresh 11.04 install - expo set to Super+s by default).

Comment: Whats even weirder is that it was working for me too, but it doesn't work anymore. I think there is a problem with Idicator applet session...

Answer (score 1):

I feel your pain. As a workaround I just mapped it to `<Super>` `<Alt>` `s` and soon enough my fingers got used to it.

Comment: Yeah I am using a similar workaround myself (<Alt>s) but I would really like to have it on <Super>s

Answer (score 0):

It may be that something else (maybe in the indicator applet) is grabbing Super-s keystrokes.  Are there any apps that could possibly be using such shortcuts?

Comment: This is caused by indicator applet session or the indicator applet complete (which has session included). If I remove both of these applets the problem goes away.